# How to pass multiple WebAPI parameters with Fiddler's Composer

Tags: asp.net, fiddler

We have a webapi project in which I have a API as follows:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Myfunc([FromBody] int a, [FromBody] int b,[FromBody] int c))
{    }
```

I launch the webapi project first.The get the link of localhost...
Then from the `fiddler->Composer` I supply the link properly.

In the input parameter section, I am trying to supply the parameters as follows:
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}

this is NOT working. How to make this work?

If I change the API as follows:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Myfunc([FromBody] myClass s))
{  }
```

and supply the above said inputs then it is working fine. Please let me know how to supply the input with multiple from Bodies......

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI doesn't allow multiple `[FromBody]`-parameters.

Furthermore, if you define a [FromBody]-parameter you cannot pass it as JSON. The following is an example of what would work:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Myfunc([FromBody] int a) {}
```

Then you're request needs to be `=5`. Note that you can't say `a=5`. That's also the reason why you can't define 3 `[FromBody]`-parameters.

To accomodate your situation, you need to accept an object that represents the JSON (as you mentioned in your last comment)

Comment: Is there any way I can pass multiple paramters in Fiddler without using an object(of class)?

Comment: You could by including it in the URL and modifying your routes. Inside the body you can only have either a JSON-object or exactly one body parameter

Comment: There's a good discussion of this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991978.aspx